# How to calculate resistors for a 555 sawtooth with an opamp sink controlling it's frequency

Tags: oscillator, 555, calculation

I modified this sawtooth-wave 555 osc and removed the ground at the 4k resistor, replaced it with an inverting opamp. The opamp produces a negative voltage and sinks the current, that previously went into ground after the 4k resistor. Applying 0-5V to the inverting input causes the 555 oscillate in different frequencies, where 5V gives the highest frequency and 0V the lowest.

[image]

The resistors on the inverting input and the feedback seem not to influence the sink but varying R1-R3 does. Via trial and error I set the values to somewhat "reasonable", that 0-5V produce a good range of frquencies although I have no clue how to calculate the values.

So, if I am using 0-5V at the inv. input, what formular could I use for the resistors to calculate the frequencies the 555 is doing at each voltage?

[Link to Falstad sim](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l5YCsA2ATI8zoA4wHYAWMI5RMbAxSkZZcDRSERAUwFowwAoAJxFQJNOqfoJAFsUcPF7gAnCLCpJYBeMlNGkLgHd5IiaKaHtAJX3rwBApabHNUu9ES6jVmwKapIK15-4%20bqh4Itp6-sEi-gDMkDZhbrEeYtEUUFwAxolp-iRSqOx4UNB4yAhkVKhyIdjVcsVw3ADmbnm50aHp4diSkUEhXYlx-D0gSYO5ktGIBhqu07NjM%207pAPLZNgTIU2l2XGCkIyqlY8P4dHQE0HI3t3Ja8Ajzy4Z5Jq5vkm2B2i2pNtFonR-ktOgllL1AhEflxzGxvF9JPCBiYpGI7I5nFwAIYgDhKcDKMaKIkqDAcDBgR5wRzSR6ufGKax44QWBLwwKqESMtkM1nYJg81ns1mGHkCwYdEASqVKOZ8cVMKUSoQyBUIyw81FUuBcFoclRqA1uPYAFwscrclsFEGi0G21jweGwToFPRueJgZEB0QIHTickE0XwdJAABMWAAzbEAVwANqbZFzCVMSRpxDIAPZWGjxcRUuicBrwaqkNAYIRcVIBWkYABqmYT2KaLC4QA)

Comment: Your diagram has nothing connected to the control voltage.  Are you sure it's correct?

Comment: The transistor is going to make this tough to put an equation on.  If you need a robust equation, there are probably better 555 circuits to use.

Comment: As for falstad sim it works without. Although it could need a cap to ground.

Comment: You're missing it.  Your title SAYS you're driving the control voltage with an op amp.  If you're not, please change the title, so we can stop wondering about it.

Comment: Edited the title. What 555 circuit would you propose instead?

Comment: I don't know, unless you're telling us exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Well I wanted to see if I can use an opamp as a control voltage input (not using the build in CV of the 555). Therefore I thought about replacing the ground for discharging the 200n cap with a variable sink. At 0V opamp output is equal to ground, at +5V at the inverting input, it's -5V below ground so SHOULD discharge the cap faster and thus increase the frequency.

Comment: Your circuit looks a bit crazy to me, and I'm one of the lower skill level people around here that really likes the 555 chip.  When I used one for a triangle wave, I set it up in 50% duty cycle astable mode(Wikipedia neatly outlines the modes) and used the capacitor voltage rather than the output.  I found in the end it was easier to get a nice triangle wave with the op amp integrator circuit which is also easy to look up.  Capacitors charge on a curve, so if you use the 555 timer you get a 1/3 VCC to 2/3 VCC triangle wave on the "straightest" parts of the capacitor curves.

Comment: Using the op amp integrator method appeared to mostly correct this, although I don't personally know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The voltage at the op-amp output is -Vin  (your 1K resistors are a bit low, 10K would be better).

The base voltage (ignoring base current) is (5V/500 - Vin/4K)* (4K||500) =

Vb = 4.44V - Vin*0.111

The emitter voltage relative to the +5 when the transistor is conducting
is Vb + 0.7 -5V = 0.14V - Vin*0.111

So the emitter current ~= collector current is
Ic ~= (Vin-1.26V)*0.111mA when Vin > 1.26V, approximately 0 for Vin < 1.26V

The 555 charges and discharges to 2/3 and 1/3 Vcc. We can ignore the discharge time for lower frequencies since there is no resistor.

So the time to charge the capacitor through 1/3 of Vcc is:

tc = \$\frac{C\cdot 1.667V}{Ic}\$ = \$\frac{200\text{nF} \cdot 1.667V}{(Vin-
1.26V)*0.111mA}\$

Ignoring the discharge time, the frequency will be:

f = \$\frac{(Vin-
1.26V)*0.111mA}{200\text{nF} \cdot 1.667V}\$ = 333(Vin - 1.26V) Hz.

If the emitter voltage gets too close to (2/3)*Vcc the current source will saturate before it charges the capacitor sufficiently, but that won't occur unless your input voltage is more like 15V.

---

If you want to make an audio-range VCO that uses cheap easily available parts, I would suggest dumping the 555 and using the one on the LM324 datasheet which uses half the chip and an inexpensive BJT (or MOSFET).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed math example, that was what I was looking for. I also have some LM324 in my box, just used the 555 here because I used an example circuit from falstad that has a sawtooth. The aim for me was to test the idea of changing one ground with an opamp current sink because I wanted to see, if pulling the discharging sink down below ground would as well change the frequency like a resistor before ground would do. Quite a "reverse": Instead of limiting the current to ground, make the sink stronger with a -V to discharge faster.

Comment: Just to clarify: I am trying to learn how oscillators work. Many of them use a capacitor and it's discharge time to adjust the frequency. A resistor before ground often limits the discharge current and thus manipulates the frequency. However replacing a resistor with a control voltage is not simple so I wondered if an opamp providing a variable current sink could do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You are charging the 555 with a constant current that is determined by \$V_B\$, the base voltage of the transistor.  The constant current is approximately $$\frac{5-(V_B+0.7)}{R_3}$$.

\$V_B\$ is set by the values of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$.  The faster you charge and discharge, the higher your frequency will be.

The voltages at Trigger and Threshold are going to be a function of your transistor.

Comment: Ok this might become complex. I am trying to understand how this works. So opamp negative voltage output would get devided by R1-R2 voltage devider, is this correct?

Comment: Not quite.  The difference between the op amp output and 5V gets divided.

Comment: The reason why you're not having luck with changing 5he op amp input is that it's too easy to turn the transistor all the way on.

Comment: But I am not having no luck. At least in the simulation, the circuit works fine, it produces a different frequency over the whole range from 0-5V on the opamp input. The issue is just that I don't know what I am doing and would like to learn how to reasobably calculate anything in this setup to be less clueless about it.